# Converting a C program to use pointers in array and have the same output

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Here is the code, I am having trouble converting it to use pointers and have the same output:

````
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i, s[4], t[4], u = 0; 
  for (i=0; i<=4; i++) 
    {
      s[i] = i;
      t[i] = i;
    } 
  printf("s : t\n");
  for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
  printf("%d : %d\n", s[i], t[i]);
  printf("u = %d\n", u);
 }```

The output of the code is this:

s : t
0 : 4
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 4
u = 0
````

My code is as follows, but the output isn't the same, can someone please help:

```
int main() {
  int i, 
    *s[4], 
    *t[4], 
    *u=0;
  for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
      s[i] = &i;
      t[i] = &i;
    }
  printf("s:t\n");
  for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    printf("%d:%d\n",*s[i],*t[i]);
printf ("u=%d\n", *u);
}
```

Comment: This makes every element of every array *point to the same thing*, so of course the output is different.  (Not sure in what sense this is an upgrade.)

Comment: Please don't put spaces around array indexing, it's unusual and hard to read. `s[i]` instead of `s [ i ]`

Comment: `i <= 4` should be `i < 4`. You're writing outside the array bounds.

Comment: That probably isn't what those who set you the task had in mind.  Keep the original arrays.  Add `int *sp = s; int *tp = t;` and then `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { *sp++ = i; *tp++ = i; }`.  Reinstate the spaces around the colon in the print format statements.  Now you can use `sp = s; tp = t; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("%d : %d\n", *sp++, *tp++);` to print the data, avoiding the problems with accessing the arrays out of bounds.

Comment: Please fix the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution that I am not sure if this might be what you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i, s[4], t[4], u=0;
    
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
      *(s+i) = i;
      *(t+i) = i;
    }
    printf("s:t\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        printf("%d:%d\n",*(s+i),*(t+i));
    
    int *ptrToU = &u;
    printf ("u=%d\n", *ptrToU);
 }
```

Arrays in C are indexed starting at 0. Your loops had `i<=4`, but had to be changed to `i<4` to prevent an out-of-bounds error.

In your original code, you had:

```
int *s[4];
```

This creates an array of 4 pointers to `int`. The question becomes, what do these pointers point to?

Your code:

```
s[i] = &i;
```

set each `int` pointer to point to the memory location of your variable `i`. Since `i` was not changing its memory location, every pointer in `s[i]` pointed to the same location. Hope this helps some.

Comment: To get the same out put as the given code, I added the "i<=4", and now the output is the same. Thank You!

Comment: Just remember that int s[4] creates an array with 4 elements and to access these elements you use a ZERO based index, s[0] = first element, s[1] = second element, s[2] = third element and s[3] = fourth element, you can do s[4] but this will access memory that is outside your array.

Comment: Hey Adam, can I ask what `*(s+i) = i;` and `*(t+i) = i;` mean?

Comment: In C, what you are doing is managing memory, so when you declare an array using int s[4], the 's' is actually a pointer to the first memory location of the array. You can use pointer arithmetic to go the second location of the array using (s + 1), the * in front of (s + i), de-references the pointer to the actual contents of the memory location. *(s + i) is the same as s[i]. Pointers are a little confusing, but well worth trying to understand.

Comment: @CeNerdNeedsHelp Here is a good video that explains pointers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw